# What's the strategy of iPhone/Android responding to ARP request

Tags: networking, ping, ethernet, libpcap, arp

When I use `arping` to send ARP request(I know a sleeping iPhone doesn't reply to ICMP ping) to sleeping iPhones/Androids(means they are on but the screen is dark) connected on the same wifi, the iPhone replies to me like this:

```
ARPING 10.109.201.139
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
42 bytes from e0:ac:cb:b0:22:5b (10.109.201.139): index=0 time=20.201 msec
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
42 bytes from e0:ac:cb:b0:22:5b (10.109.201.139): index=1 time=65.401 msec
Timeout
```

but occasionally, the iPhone replies continually. Sometimes it doesn't answer the arping at all. Android answers like so:

```
ARPING 10.109.201.119
Timeout
42 bytes from c0:ee:fb:01:f4:fd (10.109.201.119): index=0 time=78.345 msec
42 bytes from c0:ee:fb:01:f4:fd (10.109.201.119): index=1 time=148.228 msec
42 bytes from c0:ee:fb:01:f4:fd (10.109.201.119): index=2 time=217.777 msec
42 bytes from c0:ee:fb:01:f4:fd (10.109.201.119): index=3 time=84.933 msec
Timeout
42 bytes from c0:ee:fb:01:f4:fd (10.109.201.119): index=4 time=174.140 msec
42 bytes from c0:ee:fb:01:f4:fd (10.109.201.119): index=5 time=78.559 msec
```

It seems Android is more positive. So what's the strategy of iPhone/Android responding to ARP request([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42384631/whats-the-strategy-of-dns-sd-services-responding-to-mdns-query) post may be related)? May home-grade routers be related to this?
Actually I'm writing an ARP scanner with libpcap(I can provide the golang code if that helps), so how can I detect phones as much as possible?

---

ps: I know this question is kind of off-topic, but it really annoys me where I should put this question, Super User doesn't allow questions about phones, Ask different is not proper as this question is not only about Apple hardware or software. I put it on [networkengineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39155/whats-the-strategy-of-iphone-responding-to-arp-request), but it's put on hold as off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

both my wife's sleeping iphone and sleeping ipad seem to respond to an icmp ping request fine when sent via the .net ping.send method detailed 
[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb7xxkfx(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-).

I use this in a program which I wrote myself and have recently made available as freeware at
[http://www.rlatour.com/myarp](http://www.rlatour.com/myarp/)

Also [this post](https://github.com/pimatic/pimatic/issues/209) say that it works using another program called [tcping](https://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php)

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the links. Seems it varies with phones/routers.